# how can get original value from hash value?

Tags: hash

My original Text : "sanjay" 
SHA-1 Text : "25ecbcb559d14a98e4665d6830ac5c99991d7c25"

Now how can i get original value - "sanjay"  from this hash value ?

is there any code or algorithm or method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No.** That's usually the point -- the process of hashing is normally one-way.

This is especially important for hashes designed for passwords or cryptology -- which differ from hashes designed, for say, hash-maps. Also, with an unbounded input length, there is an infinite amount of values which result in the same hash.

One method that can be used is to hash a bunch of values (e.g. brute-force from aaaaaaaa-zzzzzzz) and see which value has the same hash. If you have found this, you have found "the value" (the time is not cheap). "Rainbow tables" work on this idea (but use space instead of time), but are defeated with a nonce salt.

Comment: Well, you *can* do it, but it's really inefficient and time consuming. +1 for the logical answer.

Answer (score -1):

From what I've been taught on the subject, if you were the one that turned your value into a hash value, chances are you have full access to the hash function, and would be able to reverse it in the same way. If you *only* have the original value and the end value, and don't know what hash function was used, you can't really reverse it without doing what was said above (going over every possibility).